# Orphan lines with memoir

Tags: widows-orphans

I have read that for memoir in order to set separation between paragraphs you use

```
\abnormalparskip{6pt}
```

However I have a question: Does it fix to 6pt or does it allow a little variation between minus and max setting \parskip. If the behaviour is differnt how can I set it to give a min an a max. I have some orphan lines which I want to remove, but using clubpenaty and widowpenalty makes the document look ugly.

```
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 0.2 \baselineskip minus 0.2 \baselineskip}
```

I don't know how can I write a mwe for this issue. Sorry for that.

Edit: MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside, a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish, es-noquoting, es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[spanish]{translator}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[a4paper, 
            hmargin = 2.5cm,
            vmargin = 2.5cm,
            twoside,
            includefoot,
            includehead,
            bindingoffset = 0.1cm
             ]
             {geometry}


\setlength{\parindent}{1em}
\setsecnumdepth{subsubsection} %Numeracion hasta subsection
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
%\setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus4mm minus3mm}
\abnormalparskip{6pt} % este es el que hay que usar en memoir 12

%Headers
\openright

\pagestyle{ruled}%

%\clubpenalty=10000
%\widowpenalty=10000

\begin{document}
\vspace*{55em}

xx xxxx xx xx xxxxxxxx xx xxxxxxxxxxx xx xxxxxxx xxx xxxxxxxxxxxx xx xxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx, xxxxxxxxxx xx xx xxxxxx xxx xxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxx xxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx, xx xxxxxx xx xx xx, xxx xxxxxxxx xx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx x xxx xxxxx xx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx xx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xx xxx xxxxxxx xx xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx x xxx, xxxx xx xxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxx, xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xx xxx xxxxxxxxxx xx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xx xx xx x xx xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxx xx.
\end{document}
```

Comment: You hint that you have a question about orphans but all your code fragments are about parskip which is more or less unrelated other than the fact that any change in vertical spacing will affect page break positions. Using clubpenalty and widowpenalty "makes the document look ugly" doesn't help anyone help you, changing those settings will make it more or less likely that breaks happen leaving single lines.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But if not using penalty what can I do? I have so many orphans and widow lines. The cause my parragrahs are not so long and then it can be difficult. This is why I wanted to know if by changing parkip o something like that would be enough

Comment: You _always_ use penalties in TeX, tha's what drives the whole process. "using clubpenaty and widowpenalty makes the document look ugly" makes no sense those penalties are always added with some value, the format or class file sets them to some value perhaps you changed them and made the document look ugly but since you haven't said what value they had or what value you changed them to, or give any indication about your document at all, there is no useful comment that really anyone can make about your question. Please put a _complete_ document example into the question.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I use the default values in memoir. And as I say above I don't know how to create a mwe for this. it is such a long docoument the one I have :(

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Just a very simple question. Is it better to use penalties or to use a clearpage here and there to make those lines that are orphan or widow not to be?

Comment: Presumably by your comment you mean you changed the values in some way? If not, what did you mean by your comment? start with a copy of your document with some text that makes a bad page break on some page, delete everything except that paragraph, then add `\vspace*{...}` at the start of your example to position the paragraph where it was before with a bad break.

Comment: It's not possible to answer that comment. You can force a page to be short with `\clearpage` but if that is acceptable perhaps you should be using \raggedbottom to tell tex pages may be short or if you absolutely don't want widows/orphans perhaps you should increase the penalties. If you are generating millions of pages it is worth getting the penalty defaults such that you never need to hand correct. If you are hand writing one document you can hand tune the breaks, or change the wording to get good breaks, so it all depends...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15684/discussion-between-jlanza-and-david-carlisle).